# Compile classfile issue in Spring 3

Tags: spring, ant, javac

I have used spring framework 3 for my application.  Everything is ok while developed in 
Netbeans  But i need a custom build  and   done for the same The build created without any 
issue, but i got the following error The error occurred while calling the following method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/security/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam String userName, @RequestParam String password, 
    HttpServletRequest request) {
    ......................
```

But There is no issue while creating the war with  netbeans 
(I am sure it is about the compilation issue)
have you any experiance on this issue ...
There is any additional javac argument for compile the same (netbeans used there custom task for the compilation)

type Exception report

message

```
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
```

exception

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException: Failed to invoke handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.mypackage.security.controller.LoginController.login(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No parameter name specified for argument of type [java.lang.String], and no parameter name information found in class file either.
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:659)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 com.mypackage.security.controller.AuthFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
 org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
 org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
```

root cause

```
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException: Failed to invoke handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.mypackage.security.controller.LoginController.login(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No parameter name specified for argument of type [java.lang.String], and no parameter name information found in class file either.
 org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:171)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 com.mypackage.security.controller.AuthFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
 org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
 org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
```

root cause

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No parameter name specified for argument of type [java.lang.String], and no parameter name information found in class file either.
 org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.getRequiredParameterName(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:618)
 org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveRequestParam(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:417)
 org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:277)
 org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:163)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 com.mypackage.security.controller.AuthFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
 org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
 org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.18 logs.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Argument names are stored in the compiled code only when it's compiled in debug mode, so you should either compile it in debug mode or supply `@RequestParam` with explicit parameter names. The latter approach is more reliable because it doesn't depend on the environment:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/security/login", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam("userName") String userName, 
    @RequestParam("password") String password,  
    HttpServletRequest request) { 
    ......................
```

Comment: Awesome catch - I was tearing my hair out, looking at JDKs, maybe my Hudson server was doing something wacky...and it was this silly little thing.  Is this even documented anywhere?

Comment: Just wanted to say this saved me hours of pain, anger and cases of mountain dew.